# I read a paper where I cannot understand why “arrived girl” is incorrect, but “recently arrived girl” is correct:

Tags: english

Such participles whose corresponding verbs are intransitive verbs. We usually do not say an arrived girl, a departed friend, etc., because they come from their intransitive verbs. However, a past participle deriving from such an intransitive verb can be used as adjective as long as it is premodified by an adverb or adverbial phrase, as in

The newly arrived girl from New York is waiting for you downstairs.

The gentleman recently arrived in Las Vegas is my former professor, Dr. Palmer. The train just now arrived at the station is from New York.

(Not:*The arrived train at the station is from New York, but we can say, “The train which/that arrived at the station is from New York.)

I will miss the recently departed friends.

Her husband recently returned from USA is an engineer.

(Not: *Her husband returned from USA is an engineer.)

Please, can anyone explain me why?

Thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question for [elu.se]

Comment: ‘A departed friend’ is perfectly valid, though ‘an arrived girl’ is not. ‘Her husband, returned from the US, is an engineer’ is also fine, though it is more natural if you add ‘recently’.

Comment: Thank you for answering me, and sorry for picking the wrong site. But could you be more specific why “return girl” needs an adverb?